Why Gitlab CI contains rule doesn't work?
I am trying to setup Gitlab CI file. Made 3 jobs:
build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo "build ok"

test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - echo "test ok"
  rules:
    - changes:
        - main.py

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - echo "deploy ok"

I am trying to configure test job to run only when main.py file updated. But with this configuration test job runs every time and rule doesn't work. Could you help to find what am I doing wrong?

Per gitlab docs:

You should use rules: changes only with branch pipelines or merge request pipelines. You can use rules: changes with other pipeline types, but rules: changes always evaluates to true for new branch pipelines or when there is no Git push event. Pipelines like tag pipelines, scheduled pipelines, and manual pipelines, all do not have a Git push event associated with them. In these cases, use rules: changes: compare_to to specify the branch to compare against.

So in your case, you may want to add
test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - echo "test ok"
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"
      changes:
        - main.py

To run this test on MR only
See also:
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/job_troubleshooting.html#jobs-or-pipelines-run-unexpectedly-when-using-changes
